# Why were my comments deleted?

Tags: support, moderators, comments, deleted-comments

Ref : https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/922/what-are-dis-advantages-of-one-world-one-country

I had responded to two comments, and both had nothing which were against SE.  They were still removed.

Can the person who deleted it please inform why?

Can any other moderator please review what has happened with the comments?  If any of my comments have violated any of the norms, please let me know.  I really dont think any norms violated.  I feel it was pure favoritism.

Answer (score 6):

I deleted both of your comments, you and another user were engaging in a conversation that I felt was taking a non constructive turn. Others felt the same way, some of the comments were flagged as "rude/offensive". I'm not so sure why you think favouritism was at play here, I've also deleted a couple of comments by the other user. In fact the only reason I deleted your second comment was that it was obsolete, as it was replying to a no longer existing comment.

Comments on Stack Exchange sites are considered second class citizens. Think of them as ephemeral post it notes, their primary purpose is to ask clarifications and offer suggestions to improve a post; they can be removed at any time, especially if they become obsolete.

You can review our general comment guidelines in the ["comment everywhere" privilege page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment), a page I now realize you probably didn't know existed, since you haven't reached the reputation threshold for the privilege. Apologies, if I had realized at the time that you were brand new to the network, I would have commented and explained the deletion of the comments.

Comment: Well stated. I would add that comments' primary role is to ask for clarification or otherwise offer suggestions to improve the post. When they delve into parenthetical discussion or other use cases, they are subject and apt to be deleted. This activity is simply outside the purpose for which comments exist. Such conversations (assuming they are constructive) are better suited to our [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If you were fair you would have deleted all similar comments and not just myn.

Comment: @user1744649 - trust me, everyone gets their comments deleted. It's an equal opportunity whackin'

Comment: @user1744649 The ubiquity of comments sometimes makes them difficult to stay atop of. That doesn't mean they shouldn't be maintained at all. Saying that everyone didn't get their comments deleted does not add credence to your argument.

Comment: @RobertCartaino All of you have made what ever little trust in SE disappear.  Ref : Yuu said " Saying that everyone didn't get their comments deleted " - I never said that.  I said "have deleted all similar comments ".  I really dont hope as of now, even meta is a good place to get a fair response.

Comment: @user1744649 I'm not so sure I'm following you, none of the comments that were deleted had anything to do with improving your question, and it wasn't just your comments that were deleted. What would be the purpose of preserving a debate that had little to do with improving the question, especially since it was taking an ugly turn (from both sides)?

Comment: @YannisRizos : I agree to your point sir.  Listen me too.  Chad posted a comment questioning my edit etc.  So, I responded to that.  And then slowly, things became personal, but all the while, all I did was "responding" to a comment.  Because, if I dont respond to a comment made to me, I am not "clarifying".  And then, you did delete both my comments and Chads.  I agree.  But you DID NOT delete one of the comments he made which also belonged to "had anything to do with improving your question".  You should have deleted that also is my point. But overall I feel you just tried to do your best.

Comment: @YannisRizos : Also to clarify, The comment (which started of the whole flare), which was not deleted by you, was later deleted, once I mailed SE team.  At that point of time, I felt the reason why you did not delete was due to favoritism.  But, I might have been wrong, it might have been non-deliberate.

Comment: @user1744649: I deleted that last comment because it was redundant, not because there was anything wrong with it - both it, and Yannis's comment that remains served only to direct you *here*. You both had at least two unnecessary comments deleted, and at least one further deleted because it didn't make sense without the previous ones. Counting comments isn't really a great way to establish fairness.

Comment: I am done here.  I know comments in SE are only meant help the answer in an objective.  I have understood that.  And I know you delete all other comments.  But my question  was... there was a comment that Chad made, which also had nothing to do with making the answer any better. That was not deleted.  I really dont care about number of comments deleted.  I wont respond any further, because I feel you will all keep playing the blame game.  The only way I guess to clarify this issue is if you post all the comments and then we figure out what went wrong.  Which I know you wont do.  So, bye!